# Solving an inequality with a floor function

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Hello: I was asked to *solve* the next inequality :

$$  x^2 \leq \lfloor |x+1| - |x| \rfloor$$

I got stuck, any help will do, thanks!

Comment: What is the difference between $X$ and $x$?

Comment: @LOLA : Is difference between $X$ and $X$  ?

Comment: There is no difference, i don't know how to fix it, sorry! @zoli

Comment: Use the edit link ...

Comment: Put $x=10$ for example, the inequality is not correct.